# ajaxForm is not running when used in jquery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajaxform

why is that **ajaxForm is not running in jQuery Dialog modal confirmation** whenever it is included in a "Delete Item" button.

**Here is my jquery dialog:**

```
  <div id="deleteDialogForPartylist" title="Delete this item?">
      <form id="deleteDialogForPartylistForm" action="mEdit/editPartylist/storeDataToDb/deleteData.php">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span><span id="acronymOfTheParty" style="font-weight:bolder"></span> will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="deleteDialogForPartylistHiddenId" name="deleteDialogForPartylistHiddenId">
      </form>
  </div>
```

**Here is my script**

```
$(function(){
$( "#deleteDialogForPartylist" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  height:225,
  hide: 'fade',
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
      $("#deleteDialogForPartylist").dialog('close');
    },
    "Delete item": function() {
      $('#deleteDialogForPartylistForm').ajaxForm({
            target: '#partyListInAddCandidate',
            type: "post",
            success: function(){
                alert("Success");
                $("#deleteDialogForPartylist").dialog('close');
            }
        });
    }
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Have you checked Firebug/IE Developer Tools/Chrome Developer for any errors in your JavaScript?

Comment: I've already checked it but it didn't have any error

Comment: And the AJAX request doesn't happen at all? Or is it just the `success` function not working?

Comment: did you try `.ajaxSubmit()`? See plugin docs for explanation of differences

Comment: yes the ajax request doesn't working, I've also included the beforeSubmit with an alert() on it, and unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`.ajaxForm()` does **not** submit the form as stated in the documentation of the plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api)

In your case you should use `.ajaxSubmit()` instead, which will instantly submit your form on button-click as already suggested by charlietfl's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440618/ajaxform-is-not-running-when-used-in-jquery-dialog#comment20106965_14440618)